# Convert a decimal number to percentage in javascript

Tags: javascript, percentage

I did a code to return a json, example bellow:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "header": "<a class=\"card-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"> 12345</a>- solved-1",
    "title": "Training Summary Report",
    "description": "",
    "link": "",
    "labels": [
      {
        "filter": "type",
        "value": "course 1"
      },
      {
        "filter": "Subject",
        "value": "Sub. 1239"
      },
      {
        "filter": "Idea",
        "value": "Idea . 53"
      }
    ]
  }

    {
    "id": "12345",
    "header": "<a class=\"card-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"> 12345</a>- solved-1",
    "title": "Training Summary Report",
    "description": "",
    "link": "",
    "labels": [
      {
        "filter": "type",
        "value": "course 1"
      },
      {
        "filter": "Subject",
        "value": "Sub. 1239"
      },
      {
        "filter": "Idea",
        "value": "Idea . 53-34-98:0.0045, 98-11-00:0.09856, 44-22-88:0.09875, 22-98-90:0.3245"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

These json what I have as result.
I would like to change the decimal numbers in Idea value to percentage:

```
53-34-98:0.0045, 98-11-00:0.09856, 44-22-88:0.09875, 22-98-90:0.3245

Expect result:

53-34-98:0,45%, 98-11-00:9.8%, 44-22-88:9.875%, 22-98-90:32%
```

So the result become:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "header": "<a class=\"card-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"> 12345</a>- solved-1",
    "title": "Training Summary Report",
    "description": "",
    "link": "",
    "labels": [
      {
        "filter": "type",
        "value": "course 1"
      },
      {
        "filter": "Subject",
        "value": "Sub. 1239"
      },
      {
        "filter": "Idea",
        "value": "Idea . 53-34-98:0,45%, 98-11-00:9.8%, 44-22-88:9.875%, 22-98-90:32%"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My code is the following:

```
result = ""
            if(queryResult.final_Matrix[index] == null){
                if(queryResult.idea[index] != null){
                    result = "Idea. " + queryResult.idea[index]
                }
            }
            else{
                result = "Idea. " + queryResult.final_Matrix[index]  // the result of this line is: "value": "Idea . 53-34-98:0,45%, 98-11-00:9.8%, 44-22-88:9.875%, 22-98-90:32%"
            }
```

Example final_Matrix column dataset:

```
53-34-98:0.0045, 98-11-00:0.09856, 44-22-88:0.09875, 22-98-90:0.3245
```

Someone can help me please to change my code to convert the decimal number to percentage ?
Thank you

Comment: you need to do two things, first splitting the value into several values, e.g. you get 53-34-98:0.0045, so you split this in 2 variables 53-34-98 and 0.0045, then, the value that you are after is 0.0045 (the second variable) *100 and then you add the following character '%'. If the single initial variable receives several values, you use the ',' to split them

Comment: I think you meant `53-34-98:0.45%` instead of `53-34-98:0,45%`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first split the string containing your datas (`queryResult.final_Matrix[index]`) to get each parts separatly, then, for each parts, split again using `":"` and apply some math (multiply by 100) to get the percentage :

```js
let input = "53-34-98:0.0045, 98-11-00:0.09856, 44-22-88:0.09875, 22-98-90:0.3245";

let times = input.split(", ");

const result = [];

times.forEach((elem) => 
{
  const tempArr = elem.split(":");
  result.push(tempArr[0] + ":" + (Math.round((tempArr[1] * 100) * 100) / 100) + "%");
});

let finalResult = result.join(", ");

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop, split according to the strings, reducing the array of tokens (those separated by comma `,`) and finally rebuild the tokens with the transformed percentage values.

```js
let arr = [  {    "id": "12345",    "header": "<a class=\"card-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"> 12345</a>- solved-1",    "title": "Training Summary Report",    "description": "",    "link": "",    "labels": [      {        "filter": "type",        "value": "course 1"      },      {        "filter": "Subject",        "value": "Sub. 1239"      },      {        "filter": "Idea",        "value": "Idea . 53"      }    ]  },    {    "id": "12345",    "header": "<a class=\"card-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\"> 12345</a>- solved-1",    "title": "Training Summary Report",    "description": "",    "link": "",    "labels": [      {        "filter": "type",        "value": "course 1"      },      {        "filter": "Subject",        "value": "Sub. 1239"      },      {        "filter": "Idea",        "value": "Idea . 53-34-98:0.0045, 98-11-00:0.09856, 44-22-88:0.09875, 22-98-90:0.3245"      }    ]  }];

arr.forEach(({labels}) => {
  labels.forEach(label => {
    let [_, value] = label.value.split("Idea . ");
    if (value) {
      label.value = "Idea . " + value.split(",").reduce((a, t) => {
        let [str, perc] = t.split(":");
        if (perc) str += ":" + (Number(perc.trim()) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"
        return a.concat(str);
      }, []).join();
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the object conversion using string `split`, `join` methods.

```js
const convert = item => {
  const labels = item.labels.map(label => {
    if (label.value.includes("Idea")) {
      return {
        ...label,
        value: label.value
          .split(",")
          .map(val => {
            const strs = val.split(":");
            const last = strs.pop();
            strs.push(`${Math.round(Number(last) * 100 * 100) / 100}%`);
            return strs.join(":");
          })
          .join(",")
      };
    } else {
      return { ...label };
    }
  });
  return {
    ...item,
    labels
  };
};

const arr = [
  {
    id: "12345",
    header:
      '<a class="card-link" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> 12345</a>- solved-1',
    title: "Training Summary Report",
    description: "",
    link: "",
    labels: [
      {
        filter: "type",
        value: "course 1"
      },
      {
        filter: "Subject",
        value: "Sub. 1239"
      },
      {
        filter: "Idea",
        value: "Idea . 53"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "12345",
    header:
      '<a class="card-link" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> 12345</a>- solved-1',
    title: "Training Summary Report",
    description: "",
    link: "",
    labels: [
      {
        filter: "type",
        value: "course 1"
      },
      {
        filter: "Subject",
        value: "Sub. 1239"
      },
      {
        filter: "Idea",
        value:
          "Idea . 53-34-98:0.0045, 98-11-00:0.09856, 44-22-88:0.09875, 22-98-90:0.3245"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(arr.map(convert));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) loop  to your raw data
2) on the key 'label', search the array with 'filter'==='Idea'
3) perform split and join to convert

```
data=[{...'label':{'filter':'Idea'...}...},{}];

var labels=[],valueInd=[],value=[],div2=[];
data.map((element)=>{
  labels = element.labels;
  valueInd=labels.findIndex(elem=>elem.filter==='Idea');
  value=labels[valueInd].value;
  value=value.split(' . ')[0]+ ' . '+value.split(' . ')[1].split(',').map((elem)=>{
          var div2=elem.split(':');
         return div2.length>1?div2[0]+':'+(Number(div2[1])*100).toFixed(2)+'%':div2[0];
  }).join(',');
  labels[valueInd].value=value;
});

console.log(data);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kopLe2cv/2/)